# How to create web page profile

Tags: symfony

i'm new in symfony and i want to create a user profile like this exemple [profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CN82.png)

```
<link href="{{ asset('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('bower_components/bootstrap-extension/css/bootstrap-extension.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/animate.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"
```

Please excuse my english .

Comment: what did you try so far and didn't work ?

Comment: I generate crud for user entity

Comment: This question is too broad and off-topic for SO. You should go through [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Finally, if you are sure your question fits the rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a useful, well formed/formatted and on-topic question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all that you need is to extend the FosUserBundle

If you have already configured you must have at least the User Entity extended.

You can create there the new fields and add this new fields to entity, form, views

You can find more documentation in the FosUser

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html

https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_templates.html

Other Tip: You can copy past any controller from vendors friensdofsymfony in your extended and change their behavior

Comment: i have problem with overriding templates : assetic bundle and bootstrap are installed but when i integrate login template in login view , it doesn't work

Comment: Could you edit your post with your code, then I can check what are you missing

Comment: great but I don't know your structure of folders and symfony version. With symfony 3.4 all the data is saved at web, in older versions it gets from src/Resources/public

It is how do you need to set up in Symfony 3.4 

<link href="{{ asset('bundles/app/assets ........

Assuming you have the folder /web/bundles/app/

Comment: symfony version is 3.4 , in src\SmsingBundle\Resources\public i put   bower_components/bootstrap-extension/css/bootstrap-extension.css   and        css/animate.css

Comment: IF you are in symfony 3.4 you must work directly at /web/ not inside the src/xxxxxx  

You are trying to work like the old way https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-smarter-assets-install-command